# Highly dimensional Monte Carlo integration over state space

Tags: ordinal-data, monte-carlo, high-dimensional, numerical-integration

I am trying to estimate the following expectation value
$$\mu_f = \sum_x f(x) \Pr(x)$$
for a function $f(x)$ defined for every point $x=(x_1,...,x_p)$ in ordinal state space $\Omega$ (i.e. a discrete phase space). The problem is that the effective amount of dofs $p$ is typically huge: $p$ ~ 9000, but 16,000 in the worst case.

Every dof $x_i \in \Omega$ is completely independent and has 2 to 6 outcomes ('branches') with a known probability determined by a previous algorithm. Here's a plot of the distribution of branch counts and the typical distribution of $\Pr(x_i)$ for each set of possible outcomes.

[image: bc]
[image: Pr]

I can easily generate configurations according to $\Pr(x)$, but not many: $n \approx p$ samples is already a very heavy task for my laptop. In general each configuration $x$ represents a network and $f$ can be a complex network statistic.

To make each sample count, I tried sequential importance sampling as a variance reducing technique. Although my algorithm for $\Pr(x)$ enabled me to produce a very neat biased approximating distribution $q$, the weights $w = p/q$ for a sample simply explode (~3.4$^{1700}$) because of the size of $p$.

As a final very important remark, most (about 3 times $p$) links **have a known outcome** and are fixed in the simulation of the network. So only 25% actually vary in the computation of $f$ for a configuration (these are the 'effective dofs').

I scanned the literature and Cross Validated (including [Using MCMC to evaluate the expected value of a high-dimensional function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/using-mcmc-to-evaluate-the-expected-value-of-a-high-dimensional-function)) but it seems that the amount of dofs is just too big, and the distribution too ... specific. Aggregating similar links can bring the effective amount of dofs to a minimum of $p \approx$ 4000.

So my **question** is: how can I calculate expected values for an arbitrary function $f$ of a huge collection of independent discrete variables, preferably with an variance/error estimate?

I spent many days trying to solve this problem, but I realize I need help. I would appreciate any clue and thank you all for your time!